# Possible to centrally deploy website credentials in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

We would like to deploy the credentials (user, password) of a couple of websites to all Firefox installations in our network. Is there a way to populate the password manager via script, autoconfig, policies? The goal is to avoid having to enter the credentials manually on many machines.

Comment: There are plenty of password manager extensions for firefox that connect to central repositories like lastpass, but specific software recommendations are off-topic here. Otherwise, you could also insecurely import a list of credentials from a central .csv or .html file following the steps here for example: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-login-data-file

Comment: @Cpt.Whale The request is for, “Is there a way to populate the password manager via script, autoconfig, policies?” and is not a software recommendation.

Comment: Passwords are stored encrypted in Firefox, so a script won't work. Depending on the website, the easiest might be to sync the session cookie(s). Otherwise, create a firefox account, and create a profile on each machine. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles

Comment: What might be better suited though is to use the extension of your favorite password manager.